# Shell Script- Compare

Tags: shell

I want to compare two folders and want to save the result in a differemt file. Please not that the two folders has multiple sub folders and each sub folders has multiple files.
Please suggest me the unix command for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Diff` has a recursive option:

```
   -r
   --recursive
      When comparing directories, recursively compare any  subdirecto-
      ries found.
```

So use `diff -r root1 root2`.